# Loop over Items in a c# Dictionary

Tags: c#

I want to do something with each object in a C# Dictionary. `keyVal.Value` seems a little awkward:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Customer> keyVal in customers) {
    DoSomething(keyVal.Value);
}
```

Is there a nicer way to do this that's also fast?

Comment: Do you *just* want the values? If so, use `customers.Values`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class has a [`Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx) property that you can directly iterate over:

```
foreach(var cust in customer.Values)
{
  DoSomething(cust);
}
```

An alternative, if you can use LINQ as Arie van Someren shows in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9523537/1583):

```
customers.Values.Select(cust => DoSomething(cust));
```

Or:

```
customers.Select(cust => DoSomething(cust.Value));
```

Comment: You need `.Value` in your linq.  `cust` is of type `KeyValuePair<string, Customer>` in this context

Comment: @KyleTrauberman - Thanks for the correction. I have added another alternative as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (Customer c in customers.Values)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always iterate over the keys and get the values. Or, you can iterate over just the values.

```
foreach(var key in customers.Keys)
{
    DoSomething(customers[key]);
}
```

or

```
foreach(var customer in customer.Values)
{
    DoSomething(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
customers.Select( customer => DoSomething(customer.Value) );
```

Comment: This assumes `DoSomething` returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is the values, and not the keys, then you can use `IDictionary.Values` to iterate over.

```
foreach (Customer val in customers.Values) {
    DoSomething(val);
}
```